# Parity operator action on quantized Dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, dirac-equation, parity

I am stuck on equation 3.124 on p.65 in Peskin and Schroeder quantum field theory book.

There they are claiming that:

$$P\psi(x)P=\displaystyle\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\bf p}}}\sum_s\eta_aa^{s}_{-{\bf p}}u^s(p)e^{-ipx} + \text{similar terms}.\tag{3.124}$$

where $P$ is the parity operator. From what I understand one of the transitions was claiming that: $Pe^{-ipx}=e^{-ipx}P$ although in my opinion $Pe^{-ipx}=e^{-ip\cdot (t,-\vec{x})}P$.

Can someone help me understand what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my copy of the book to hand, but I assume that $P$ is there  a linear  operator on the Hilbert space. It does not commute with the creation and annihilation *operators*:
$$
P\hat a_{\bf k} P= \hat a_{-{\bf k}},
$$
but it *does* commute with all $c$-numbers such as $e^{ipx}$. This is because  the $x$ in the exponent is just a number, and not an operator.

For example in non-relativistic field theory we have
$$
\hat \psi({\bf x}) = \sum_{\bf k} \hat a_{\bf k} e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}
$$
so
$$
P\hat \psi({\bf x}) P= \sum_{\bf k}  P\hat a_{\bf k}Pe^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}\\
= \sum_{\bf k} \hat a_{-\bf k}e^{i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}\\
= \sum_{\bf k} \hat a_{\bf k}e^{-i{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}\\
= \hat \psi(-{\bf x})
$$
so the ${\bf x}\to -{\bf x}$ comes about by the change of summation variable ${\bf k}\to -{\bf k}$ rather than by an action on the c-number  variable ${\bf x}$.

Comment: P  is the parity operator which acts on the spacetime therefore acts on $e^{ipx}$

Comment: But why doesn't parity change the c number? If parity change x to -x then I don't see why it should change a c number that is a functional of p,x. I do agree that you will get the same answer anyway in this example as the two minuses from p,X will cancel each other